# How to automatically set DART_FLAGS=' ' on every Chromium startup

Tags: command-line, dart, launcher

I use Ubuntu 14 and I want to run Chromium(which is called Dartium) from the Launcher and it automatically set `DART_FLAGS='--enable_type_checks --enable_asserts'` on every startup. At the moment I run Chromium using:

```
cd dartium
DART_FLAGS='--enable_type_checks --enable_asserts' ./chrome
```

But it's really annoying(

Comment: Why don't you add it to your system configuration? What operating system do you have? Windows has it somewhere in the control panel (environment or similar). In Linux you can add it to your ~/.bashrc. Don't know on Apple.

Comment: I would make an alias for this.

Comment: Or create a script in dartium's directory calling `chrome` with the correct flags, and then you could launch dartium with that script.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, please add your first comment as answer - it's what I want to hear! Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set environment variables in each supported operating system.
In windows you can configure them using the control panel. In Linux using for example the `~/.bashrc` file by adding `export DART_FLAGS='--enable_type_checks --enable_asserts'`. OSX probably similar.
Changes might require a reboot (or just `. ~/.bashrc` in Linux).

Comment: No reboot required. You can either just run .bashrc, or you can start a new terminal window. I'm pretty sure this is the same on Linux and OSX, but a bit of an OSX n00b.

Comment: Ah - but he's probably starting dartium by clicking on the icon, in which case he probably will have to logout/login. I usually launch it from the terminal anyway.

Comment: I just wanted to ensure someone who reads this doesn't waste time why the change has no effect. After a restart it takes effect no matter what. OS pros won't search for this answer anyway ;-)